# Cannot implicitly convert type "CRMFullProject.Lab" to "SmartSecurity.Lab"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, linq-to-entities

```
 Lab lb = Databasebase.GetSpecificLab(id);
```

This is the line where error occurs. I am accessing GetSpecificLab method from class library project in a web project.

Method made in class library:

```
public static Lab GetSpecificLab(int id) {
    using(CRMEntities ctx = new CRMEntities()) {
        Lab lb = (from ct in ctx.Labs where ct.id == id select ct).FirstOrDefault();
        return lb;
    }
}
```

Accessing in web project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CRMFullProject;
namespace SmartSecuritySystem {
    public partial class EditLab: System.Web.UI.Page {
        int id = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            if (!IsPostBack) {
                Lab lb = Databasebase.GetSpecificLab(id);
            }
```

Please help me where I am wrong?

Comment: Try providing some more information and bit more code

Comment: method made in class library:    public static Lab GetSpecificLab(int id)
        {
            using (CRMEntities ctx = new CRMEntities())
            {
                Lab lb = (from ct in ctx.Labs
                          where ct.id == id
                          select ct).FirstOrDefault();
                return lb;
            }
        }

Comment: accessing in web project: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CRMFullProject;

namespace SmartSecuritySystem
{
    public partial class EditLab : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int id = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
             if (!IsPostBack)
             {
                 Lab lb = Databasebase.GetSpecificLab(id);
                 
             }

Comment: Edit your question! Shoving code into comments is pointless. http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @Yannick Meeus thanks but my problem is solved

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't clean up your question for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have same class defined in both namespaces.
Assuming you want you result in CRMFullProject.Lab class

Try this:

```
CRMFullProject.Lab lb = Databasebase.GetSpecificLab(id);
```

Comment: Please guide me how to insert image into database and how to retrieve  it in asp.net c#

Comment: First of all, it's not nice to insert images into database. It will have direct hit on the performance. If you want to achieve similar thing, better use an FTP server to save image and put the address of that image in database. If you still want to save image to database, add a column in db as varbinary max and insert binary data directly using file stream or any stream.